# This CLI is deprecated after heroku-cli: Installing CLI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've got a problem. I reinstalled heroku - and when I run first command after reinstall `heroku run bash --app myapp` everything was all right, but `heroku-cli: Installing CLI... 22.43MB/22.43MB` was launched, and when I had to run bash once again, I've got this statement:

```
 ▸    heroku-cli: This CLI is deprecated. Please reinstall from https://cli.heroku.com
 ▸    Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined
 !    error getting commands pid 98821 exit 1
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try now, I had exactly the same error since some minutes ago, but now it's working.
I have reinstalled several times without results, but maybe it was an Heroku bugs and now it's solved